# Repeated use of same Textbox with overwrite function

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have a small problem and can not find the solution on the web, guess I am the first asking of this. So I am asking you for help. :)

I have a UserForm, and in it is a Textbox1, that serves as an input box for a QR code scanner. All works fine, for the first scan, but does not on the second, third, ... is it possible to create code that, when the data gets entered via the QR scanner, the cursor should go back to the beginning of the TextBox1 after each scan? So a loop of a kind.

**process the ID and write data to Textbox1 -> empty the Textbox1->put cursor back to start of Textbox1 and wait for the next scanner input -> repeat steps**

In TextBox1 is a code that sorts the text entered to the TextBox, and copies it to other TextBoxes based on the ID. The ID is 10 symbols long (Pxxxx_xxxx).

Thanks for any help,
Simon

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWpFj.jpg)

Comment: So the Textbox1 receives the ID from the HID device, but why do you need the cursor to be moved and what's this "code that sorts the code entered to the box"?

Comment: @Notus_Panda Yes, in Textbox1 is written data from scaner. The cursor neds to be moved automaticaly back because we scann a lot of IDs one after another, and they get sorted in Textbox1.

Comment: But what does "go back to the beginning of the textbox" and then "sorted in Textbox1" mean? Do you either want to have the code receive multiple scans in the same textbox (have multiple codes in the textbox at one given time) or have your code process the ID -> empty the Textbox1/overwrite the ID -> process next one? Can you give a screenshot of an example?

Comment: process the ID -> empty the Textbox1/overwrite the ID -> process next one

One scan at a time.

Comment: It sounds like you need to respond to an event, set focus back to Textbox1, and select all the text (or clear the text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This code seems to do the trick, but I do not know if, there are some
not needed lines in it. I did edited it a little.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim LastRowFilled As Long
Dim DataArray(1 To 4) As String
Dim i As Integer
If Me.TextBox1 = "" Then
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
Else
    
    
    LastRowFilled = xlLastRow + 1
    For i = 1 To 4
        Worksheets("DN 3.0.").Cells(LastRowFilled, i).Value = DataArray(i)
    Next i
    Me.TextBox1 = ""
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work then? I didn't really understand why focus would get lost from the textbox if you want everything automated but this should work. For testing purposes, I only copy pasted some ID's into TextBox1, I don't have a QR scanner going.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnStop_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim testStr As String, valueStr As String
    If Not Len(Me.TextBox1.value) = 0 Then
        testStr = TextBox1.Text
        Me.TextBox2.value = Left(testStr, 5) 'just manipulating other textboxes for testing
        valueStr = Right(testStr, 5)
        Me.TextBox3.value = valueStr
        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & lRow).value = valueStr
        Me.TextBox1.value = ""
        'in my case this next line isn't necessary
        Me.TextBox1.SetFocus 'use this in case in your code you lose focus of it
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Hope this helps, let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Hello, no it does not work for my case. I have added a Image to my question and edited it a little to better understand it.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is with my code tbh, even with the picture. Of course I'm not using an array because there was no prior mention to it. This was just an example of setting focus and keeping focus. What exactly does not work for you?